# What settings can I do on Google Chrome to convert codes that denotes formula on a webpage into a readable format for Non-CS students?

Tags: html, google-chrome

So I need to study this webpage in the link here but I found out all the calculations were denoted in codes that I can't read as I am not trained in CS at all. Is there any settings I can do to convert the codes into the readable format, instead of in codes?
Link
https://opentextbc.ca/principlesofaccountingv1openstax/chapter/analyze-and-record-transactions-for-the-issuance-and-repurchase-of-stock/

Example of caluculations/formula denoted in code:
***(\left(?21.50-?1.50\right)\phantom{\rule{0.2em}{0ex}}×\phantom{\rule{0.2em}{0ex}}8,000=?160,000)***
And all the dollar values become '**?**'

Comment: That page is just broken — it's a poorly done import.

Comment: Compare: https://openstax.org/books/principles-financial-accounting/pages/14-2-analyze-and-record-transactions-for-the-issuance-and-repurchase-of-stock

Comment: Alright @hobbs. Thanks for the link